# Sometimes upvotes are provocative!

Tags: discussion

The question may be a very normal one and its answer is also *very* normal, nevertheless I notice ***very, very*** abnormal upvotes for both the question and the answer! On the other hand, some questions and answers are real valuable and still don't get the right appreciation.

This is my notice and I'm not sure if someone agrees with me.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I answered the following question:

["Friday afternoon" vehicle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2721/friday-afternoon-vehicle)

then someone else gave the same answer *after* I did, and then he got <strike>four</strike> *six* upvotes and accepted and I didn't get even one.

Upvotes are strange, but then again this is much the same as on stackoverflow.com, so if you're used to the bizarrities of Stack Overflow this won't surprise you too much. The important thing is that it averages out over time, so e.g. a fairly obvious answer like this:

[What is the correct way to pronounce 'router'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2389/how-to-pronounce-router/2390#2390)

can get you seventeen upvotes (and two downvotes as well for some reason).

Comment: On the Friday afternoon question, the other answer was more detailed.  Your answer said (paraphrase) A car made when everyone wants to go home early.  The other answer said (paraphrase) A car made when everyone wants to go home early *resulting in a lower quality product*.  That extra bit is a major part of the answer and is probably why the other answer was upvoted.

Comment: On the Router question, the downvotes were likely from Americans who don't pronounce the two words differently.

Comment: I was one of the down-votes on that question. My reasoning that the claims made in the answer were personal opinion and unsubstantiated.

Comment: @Shinto Sherlock: "it averages out over time". Boy! I like that part! +1 and accepted.

Comment: @JohnFx: I don't see anything which could be described as personal opinion in that post, or opinion of any kind.